# Way to release technology with license, without necessity to pay money

Tags: patent-applications

I've got serious technology, something that can change way we handle stuff today. Problem is, that I don't have the money to fill in international patent. How should I proceed? I want humans to use technology I posses.

I don't want to be poor for the rest of my life. If I release really good technology for free, and ask for some donations to make a living, will I get more than $20 dollars a year?

Answer (score -1):

Licensing questions are off topic, but I'll take a crack at answering as best as I can. What I generally see from the start-up companies I work with is that they first file a provisional patent application in the US. This can be done with minimal cost and legal resources. Having filed a provisional application, the start-up then approaches funding sources like venture capitalists or angel investors to discuss raising money to pursue development of the technology. These discussions are best done with a confidentiality agreement in place. You don't really need a lawyer for these as you can find templates on the internet. Search under "confidentiality agreement template" or "non-disclosure agreement template". If you haven't filed an application, then a CDA or NDA is an absolute requirement before any discussions. Assuming you are successful at raising money, you can then fund the acquisition of patents necessary to out-license your technology.